# Ordered list repeats number 1

Tags: php, html

my index.php file:

```
    <?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `pic_id` FROM image_tag ORDER BY `pic_id`");

    while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $pic_id = $run['pic_id'];
    $left = $run['left'];
    $top = $run['top'];
?>

<div id = "taggednum" style = "top:<?php echo $top; ?>; left:<?php echo $left; ?>;">
<ol><li rel ="<?php echo $pic_id; ?>"></li></ol>
</div>

<?php
    }
?>
```

It doesn't show the correct number on the list. It numbered '1' for the entire list. What is the problem here?

Comment: Please fix your sql syntax also: SELECT `pic_id`,`top`,`left` FROM image_tag ORDER BY `pic_id`".

Comment: And while you're at it, be advised that the `mysql*` libraries you use are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 2):

You restart your order list all the time with `<ol></ol>`. to fix, you should have the result like this:

```
<ol>
   <li>item 1
   <li>item 2
</ol>
```

to do so, put your `<ol>` and `</ol>` tags outside of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You put your `<ol>` and `</ol>` in there every time. You shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "taggednum">
    <ol><?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `pic_id`, `left`, `top` FROM image_tag ORDER BY `pic_id`");

        while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $pic_id = $run['pic_id'];
            $left = $run['left'];
            $top = $run['top'];
            ?><li style="top:<?php echo $top; ?>; left:<?php echo $left; ?>;" rel="<?php echo $pic_id; ?>"></li><?php
        }
    ?></ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your `<ol>` out side `while` loop

Please check this portion of your code,

```
$left = $run['left'];
$top = $run['top'];
```

I guess you should use * in your query

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "taggednum">

<ol>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `pic_id` FROM image_tag ORDER BY `pic_id`");

    while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $pic_id = $run['pic_id'];
    $left = $run['left'];
    $top = $run['top'];
?>


<li rel ="<?php echo $pic_id; ?>" style = "top:<?php echo $top; ?>; left:<?php echo $left; ?>;"></li>


<?php
    }
?>
</ol>
</div>
```

This should do the trick. You are creating each time a new ordered list.